# Rect.setGradient is not a function in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I saw on questions about set background as gradient in fabricjs. They said that to use setGradient on object of fabric.Rect but when I use it cause error rect.setGradient is not a function. Any solution ? Thank you

```
let rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top: 0, left : 0, width : $("canvas").width(), height: $("canvas").height(), fill : "#000"
    });
rect.setGradient("fill",{
             properties here
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The `setGradient` method was removed in Fabric v4 (see http://fabricjs.com/v4-breaking-changes).

Here is the current way to set a gradient fill.

```js
obj.set('fill', new fabric.Gradient({
  //gradient options
  type: 'linear',
  gradientUnits: 'pixels', // or 'percentage'
  coords: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 50, y2: 0 },
  colorStops:[
    { offset: 0, color: 'red' },
    { offset: 1, color: 'green'}
  ]
}));
```